# create sequence depending on a Many2one field

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I have this object `project.task` that has many situations `project.task.situation` . In `project.task.situation` model I want to create a sequence so I added this record:

```xml
<record id="sequence_project_task_situation_seq" model="ir.sequence">
    <field name="name">Project Task Situation Sequence</field>
    <field name="code">project.task.situation</field>
    <field name="prefix">Situation N°</field>
    <field eval="1" name="number_next"/>
    <field eval="1" name="number_increment"/>
    <field eval="False" name="company_id"/>
</record>
```

In python code I added this:

```py
name = fields.Char(string='Situation Number', readonly=True)
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    seq = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('project.task.situation') or '/'
    vals['name'] = seq
    return super(ProjectTaskSituation, self).create(vals)
```

what I want is each task has its own situation sequence. For example for `task1` I create 2 situations so I have `Situation N°1` and `Situation N°2` after that I want to create situations for `task2` so I'll get `Situation N°3` and `Situation N°4` . Which is not good cause I want for each task to start count sequence from the start. Is this possible? How is that?

Comment: yes u can do it using sql query. instead of ir.sequence

Comment: can you give me more details on how to do this @MrRobot